# Prevent android apps from being uninstalled?

Tags: android, security, uninstallation

so I'm developing an application locker. Ive developed the core locking functionality. i want to add the functionality of preventing an unauthorized user from uninstalling any locked apps on the device. What i want to do is when a particular app is locked and someone tries to uninstall it,i want to show my locking screen first.If the user enters the right password then he /she should be able to uninstall the application. Ive seen other applications like [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) and [McAfee Antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wsandroid.suite) having this functionality. can anybody advice me on how to achieve this functionality. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can track the uninstallation of app by implementing [Device Admin API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use wipedata() method of device admin api